# How do I apply changes in package-lock and package json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I manually changed my dependencies in `package-lock.json` and `package.json` files. How do I now apply those changes to my `node-modules` without updating/touching other dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run command

```
npm i
```

or

```
npm install --save
```

`npm i` command will install all your dependencies into your local machine which are available in the file.

> PS: It is not recommended approach to directly update `package.json` file, always install package using command `npm i packageName --save` or `npm i packageName --save --dev`. This will install as well as Update your `package.json` file too.

Comment: Forgot to mention, will it change my other dependencies? like ```some package``` was '1.0.0' and will it change it to '^1.0.0'. I just need to avoid it

Comment: I think if you run only `npm i` then it will not update your file, untill you run `npm i --save`, not sure though